# data.table Rolling sum over past 24 hours

Tags: r, datetime, data.table, rolling-computation

I have a `data.table` object with date, time and an amount. I would like to calculate the rolling sum of the amount, so that at any point in time, I can know how much of that quantity was cumulated over the past 24 hours.

The challenge is that the number records are unpredictable. There can be anywhere from 10-30 amounts recorded in a single day. What's an elegant solution for this?

No reason it has to be `data.table`, that's just a personal preference.

```
> dt
            Day                Time amount
  1: 2023-04-06 0000-01-01 00:06:00   2.20
  2: 2023-04-06 0000-01-01 03:57:00   2.40
  3: 2023-04-06 0000-01-01 06:49:00   3.00
  4: 2023-04-06 0000-01-01 07:50:00   0.25
  5: 2023-04-06 0000-01-01 08:59:00   2.40
 ---                                      
338: 2023-04-29 0000-01-01 05:48:00   1.70
339: 2023-04-29 0000-01-01 06:51:00   1.90
340: 2023-04-29 0000-01-01 07:45:00   0.60
341: 2023-04-29 0000-01-01 09:27:00   1.70
342: 2023-04-29 0000-01-01 10:10:00   1.00
> 
> str(dt)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  342 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ Day   : Date, format: "2023-04-06" "2023-04-06" "2023-04-06" "2023-04-06" ...
 $ Time  : POSIXct, format: "0000-01-01 00:06:00" "0000-01-01 03:57:00" "0000-01-01 06:49:00" "0000-01-01 07:50:00" ...
 $ amount: num  2.2 2.4 3 0.25 2.4 2.25 2 0.5 2 0.5 ...
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> 
>
```

Comment: Provide reproducible example

Comment: additionally, it appears that your `Time` should either be combined with `Day` (as a full timestamp) or just time-of-day (perhaps `lubridate::hms`?). Since you say "past 24 hours", I think the former.

Answer (score 2):

First, replace your `Day` and `Time` columns with a single column (in my example below, that single column is `date`. Then, simply join `dt` on itself using a non-equi join, and use `.EACHI`

```
dt[dt[, .(date, lower = date-(24*60*60))],
   on=.(date>=lower, date<=date),
   .(cum_amount = sum(amount)),
   .EACHI
][,c(2,3)]
```

Output:

```
                    date cum_amount
                  <POSc>      <num>
  1: 2023-04-06 00:06:00       6.23
  2: 2023-04-06 00:37:00       6.73
  3: 2023-04-06 00:47:00      13.48
  4: 2023-04-06 01:22:00      21.00
  5: 2023-04-06 01:25:00      24.62
 ---                               
338: 2023-04-29 02:51:00      46.02
339: 2023-04-29 06:32:00      42.74
340: 2023-04-29 06:49:00      50.27
341: 2023-04-29 09:40:00      45.30
342: 2023-04-29 10:10:00      37.86
```

Input:

```
set.seed(123)

dt = data.table(
  date = seq(from=as.POSIXct("2023-04-06 00:06"),to=as.POSIXct("2023-04-29 10:10"),by="min")
)[c(1,33725, sample(2:33724,340))][, amount:=round(runif(342,0,8),2)][order(date)]
```